# Silverlight: How to style the validation tooltip?

Tags: silverlight, validation, tooltip

I did some searching but it wasn't what I was looking for. So, does anyone know a way how to style the validation tooltip in Silverlight(the thing in the green border)?

[alt text http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/222/validationtooltip.png](http://img689.imageshack.us/img689/222/validationtooltip.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best Regards,

~K

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't easily provide a style for the validation tooltip without effectively styling the entire Textbox control.  Blend makes this fairly easy if you are familiar with using that design tool.  However if your a dyed in the wool coder like me then...

- Goto this page on MSDN [TextBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc645061(VS.95).aspx)
- Copy the vsm namespace alias to your UserControl xaml
- Copy the TextBox style into UserControls.Resources give it at an x:Key name (say MyTextBoxStyle")
- Copy the ValidationToolTipTemplate from the web page to the UserControls.Resources, paste it **above** the TextBox style.  It already has an x:Key name that the TextBox style will be referencing.
- Add `Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}"` to your TextBox in the data grid.

Now you play around with the validation elements of the templates to get your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

The validation messages are displayed as a visual state. you can get to these (and edit them) as templates directly from blend.