# about silverlight textbox validation

Tags: silverlight

The data validation for textbox in silverlight 4 has a red tooltip that flies out to the right.

I don't want the color of textbox's border change to red,
and don't need red tooltip neither.

How can I make this tooltip disappear when validation failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find how you can style the validation tooltip:
[Silverlight: How to style the validation tooltip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899496/silverlight-how-to-style-the-validation-tooltip)

This can solve your problem.

In addition you could disable the validation on your binding. How do you validate your input? If you have set the NotifyOnValidationError and the ValidatesOnExceptions to true, remove it (it is false by default). Or if you use validation via INotifyDataErrorInfo you have to set the ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors to false (this is true by default).

Hope this helps.

BR,

TJ

Comment: Hi TJ,  
Thanks for your reply, I validate input by INotifyPropertyChanged interface. If I set the NotifyOnValidationError and the ValidatesOnExceptions to false, how can I catch information when validation fails. 

Restyle the validation tooltip, it does work.  
But,If I still use INotifyPropertyChanged interface to validate input, and don't restyle the validation tooltip. 
Is there something else way?

Comment: Have you considered using the INotifyDataErrorInfo to validate your data. This is the recomended way. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx. In this case you have always a list of all current errors and if you set ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors to false, no validation should be showed.